# What is the name of the elements of the filtration on a probability space?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, terminology

Given a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ one can talk about a filtration $\mathfrak{F} = \{\mathcal{F}_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, i.e. a family of sub sigma algebras $\mathcal{F}_n$ satisfying $\mathcal{F}_n\subset \mathcal{F}_{n+1}$. Is there a more precise name for the elements $\mathcal{F}_n$ of the filtration $\mathfrak{F}$ or must one settle for simply sub sigma algebras?

Comment: Filtrations are used in connection with stochastic processes. $\mathcal F_n$ is usually the collection of events observable up to time $n$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy indeed this is what I am using them for. But, for instance, I want to say something like, "We take the expectation with respect to the '___' $\mathcal{F}_n$". At first I was placing the word filtration in the single quotes but now I realize this is not correct as the filtration is the entire family of sub sigma algebras.

Comment: "We take the expectation of $X$ conditional on $\mathcal{F}_n$" or "we take the conditional expectation of $X$ wrt $\mathcal{F}_n$", or something like that.

Comment: Yes this is certainly an option, and it's what I have gone with so far, but I am still curious if there exists a more precise terminology for these sub sigma algebras which make up the filtration.